# Oracle AQ Leave stale Subscribers in the Queue

Tags: oracle, queue

We are using Oracle AQ(Advanced Queue) in our project. We see messages and subscribers keep accumulating in our AQ Queue table. It's not clear to us why there are so many subscribers and get into the error:

```
Caused by: oracle.jms.AQjmsException: ORA-24067: exceeded maximum number of subscribers for queue FUSION.FND_JMS_EXMR_QUEUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Advanced  Queue *subscribers* are not getting *stale*, but they are explicitely created with `dbms_aqadm.add_subscriber` and must be removed using `dbms_aqadm.remove_subscriber`.

You may check the subscribers for a particular queue with the following query  (substitute your queue name)

```
select CONSUMER_NAME, ADDRESS, PROTOCOL from all_queue_subscribers where QUEUE_NAME = 'QUEUE_NAME';

CONSUMER_NAME, ADDRESS, PROTOCOL
S1                      0
S2                      0
```

**Example of Removing a Subscriber**

```
DECLARE
subscriber sys.aq$_agent;
BEGIN
 subscriber := sys.aq$_agent('S1', NULL, NULL);
 dbms_aqadm.remove_subscriber(queue_name => 'queue_name', subscriber => subscriber);
END;
/
```

As [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/errmg/ORA-19999.html#GUID-2EBC717B-171A-4A9D-8C79-4B6B72D7B5CB) the maximum number of subscribers is 1024

> ORA-24067: exceeded maximum number of subscribers for queue string

> Cause: An attempt was made to add new subscribers to the specified, but the number of subscribers for this queue has exceeded the maximum number (1024) of subscribers allowed per queue.

> Action: Remove existing subscribers before trying to add new subscribers.